# How to execute add_action() function from custom plugin to Crontrol plugin or do_action()?

Tags: php, plugin-development, actions, wp-cron, oop

I created a custom plugin and I need to schedule add_action using Crontrol Plugin, the Setup class is from different php class. But the schedule action cant read the Crontrol even if I execute do_action('schedule') inside functions.php it is not working.

```
class Scheduler {
    
    public $setup;

    public function __construct()
    {

        add_action('scheduler', [$this, 'etf_scheduler_func']);
    }

    public function etf_scheduler_func() {
        $this->setup = new Setup();
        $this->setup->set_table();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't scheduled anything. That's what the Crontrol plugin shows; scheduled actions. See this for how to schedule things in WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I posted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't call the class yet, this code is now working

```
class Scheduler {
    
    public $setup;
    public static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance =& $this;

        add_action('scheduler', [$this, 'etf_scheduler_func']);
    }

    public function etf_scheduler_func() {
        $this->setup = new Setup();
        $this->setup->set_table();
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) )
            self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }
} 

Scheduler::get_instance();
```

Comment: You haven't actually answered your question. What did you do differently? The action name has changed, but why did that fix the problem? You answer should be useful to anyone who comes across this question with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, I updated the action name.